# Interval containg perfect square

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Prove that for every $k>0$, there exists $n_k$, such that for all $x>n_k$, the interval $[x,x+(2+k)\sqrt x)$ contains a perfect square.

Can someone please tell me, how to construct that $n_k$?

Comment: Can you prove that every interval of the form $[x,x+4\sqrt{x}+4)$ contains a perfect square? Can you deduce your desired statement from that?

Comment: we can use the interval of the form $[x,x+2\sqrt x+1)$.